# Can a Wizard prepare spells from other spellbooks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, wizard

I was playing as a wizard character in a campaign, and found a spellbook. I was excited at first, but then realized how expensive it would be to copy it into my own. So can I just prepare them straight from the other spellbook?